# google.api_core.exceptions: 403 The caller does not have permission

Tags: python, google-cloud-automl

i am using google cloud automl tables api , and when i execute the url request to the method it gives me this error :

> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission

the parameters is correct so why it shows me that error !

```
   @app.route('/model_train',methods=['GET','POST'])
def model_train():

    project_id = 'myproject'
    compute_region = 'us-central1'
    model_id = 'TBL7912987273010'
    file_path = 'E:/downloads/Dataset-entrainement-demain_ai_demonstrateur_attrition_Oct19_Copie.csv'
    score_threshold = '0.5'

    automl_client = automl.AutoMlClient()

    model_full_id = automl_client.model_path(
        project_id, compute_region, model_id
    )

    prediction_client = automl.PredictionServiceClient()

    params = {}
    if score_threshold:
        params = {"score_threshold": score_threshold}

    with open(file_path, "rt") as csv_file:
        content = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row in content:
            values = []
            for column in row:
                values.append({'number_value': float(column)})
            payload = {
                'row': {'values': values}
            }

            response = prediction_client.predict(model_full_id, payload)
            print("Prediction results:")
            for result in response.payload:
                print("Predicted class name: {}".format(result.display_name))
                print("Predicted class score: {}".format(result.classification.score))
```

can any one help me please !

Comment: can you add the code used for the request? to get answers faster and accurately have a look into [MCVE guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: okey bro i will add it now

Comment: have you enabled automl api on your account?
https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en

Comment: moreover, have you generated application credentials? https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?pli=1 and if yes are you passing them as environment variables?

Comment: Thank you brother it work i think now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a formal answer, basically the issue is with the permissions set for the users account on GCP IAM section.
Firstly, the automl API needs to be enabled for the project [here](http://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841?hl=en)

You then need to [generate credentials](http://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?pli=1) and pass them as environment variables. You can add the environment variables at the top of the file using the os library:

```py
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/file.json"
```

Comment: @SudiptaDhara have you enabled the API on your gcp account? it's hard to know why something works or doesn't on a completely different setting